# Componente ou Conversor PDF

Tags: delphi

Alguém conhece algum componente para Delphi XE que converte PDF para DOC ou HTML ? Ou se possível editar o PDF direto e alterar o mesmo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FoxIt disponibiliza um SDK para edição e visualização de PDF como pode ser visto [neste link](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/PDFsdk/)

Este SDK permite, entre outras coisas, suas solicitações

- Edição de Documentos PDF
- Rendenização para web de PDFs